# Sending data from iOS server to java client

Tags: java, ios, sockets, server, client

I am new to iOS development. What I want to achieve is create server on iPhone app and receive data in Java client app.
I have successfully created iPhone side server using [this](https://github.com/kirankunigiri/peertalk-simple) library

On java client side, I am receiving data from local host using same port number

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
```

I have made connection successfully.
I am tried sending number and text using this code

```
func sendObject(object: Any, type: UInt32, completion: ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
            let data = Data.toData(object: object)
            if peerChannel != nil {
                peerChannel?.sendFrame(ofType: type, tag: PTFrameNoTag, withPayload: (data as NSData).createReferencingDispatchData(), callback: { (error) in
                    completion?(true)
                })
            } else {
                completion?(false)
            }
        }

static func toData(object: Any) -> Data {
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
}
```

But I always receive '?bplist?' in java client.
Do I have to convert data from server end? Please help.

Comment: What is `Data.toData(object: object)`, and what's `object`? I'm wondering if you aren't sending NSKeyedArchived objects which won't make sense on the Java part.

Comment: static func toData(object: Any) -> Data {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
    }

Comment: That's normal. What kind of message are you trying to send? String? Something more complicate? Once you specified that, we can answer you with an relevant suggestion.

Comment: String data only

Comment: `let data = myString.data(using:.utf8)` then, not `let data = Data.toData(object: object)`.

Comment: thanks.. it worked. Just one problem, when I am sending any string data I am getting 'f' prefix. Eg. Sending "Hello", receiving "fHello". I have already checked if in printing logs or while sending or receiving end I am appending string.. but that is not the case